# R table xtab: Contingency Table conditional on exclusion factors

Tags: r, crosstab

Imagine I want to create a contingency table for mobile and gender for have the following data set:

```
df<-data.frame(read.table(header = TRUE, text = 
"Age    Gender  Mobile
13  Male    1
14  Female  1
18  Female  1
13  Male    1
13  Female  1
14  Female  0
16  Male    1
16  Female  0
16  Male    0
20  Male    0
14  Male    0
13  Female  0
25  Male    1
13  Female  0
24  Female  0"))
```

I would go about it as follows:

```
df$Gender<-factor(df$Gender)
df$Mobile<-factor(df$Mobile)
prop.table(xtabs(~Mobile+Gender, df))
```

It works fine. Now, imagine I want to compile a table for both gender and mobile for the subset of the sample that is above 18. How would you do this? I tried the following to no avail:

```
prop.table(xtabs(~Mobile+Gender, df[df$Age>18]))
```

or

```
prop.table(xtabs(~Mobile+Gender[df$Age>18], df))
```

or

```
prop.table(xtabs(~Mobile+Gender, df))[df$Age>18]
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to `subset` the rows for `Age > 18`, use `droplevels` if we need to remove the unused levels after the subsetting, get the table with `xtabs` and convert to proportion.

```
prop.table(xtabs(~Mobile+Gender, droplevels(df[df$Age>18,])))
```

Comment: ! And again you are right, mate! thanks for both the correction as well as the quick reply! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a `,` to your first attempt will also do the trick:

```
> prop.table(xtabs(~ Mobile + Gender, df[df$Age > 18,]))
      Gender
Mobile       Female         Male
     0 0.3333333333 0.3333333333
     1 0.0000000000 0.3333333333
```

There is no need to drop levels of factors that are not appearing in the table:

```
> prop.table(xtabs( ~ Mobile + Gender, droplevels(df[df$Age > 18,])))
      Gender
Mobile       Female         Male
     0 0.3333333333 0.3333333333
     1 0.0000000000 0.3333333333
```